# Which Android appstores support in-app purchases (aka in-app billing)?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have my Android game with in-app purchases. It uses Google Play IAB API 3.0. I want to publish it to other Android appstores. I understand that I will need to change my program to supports their custom IAB API. Which Android application stores support in-app billing API?

So far I have found the following four appstores that provides in-app billing API for Android developers:

- Google Play
- Amazon AppStore
- Samsung Apps
- SK T-Store

and NOOK apps has partnered with Fortumo and provides in-app billing via their API.

Are there any other Android application store that provides in-app billing API?